# SASS media query issue

Tags: ios, sass, media-queries

I have a media query that is working as it should in safari ios but text is not resizing on chrome ios.

I'm just simply trying to nest all of the breaking points for that particular h1 tag.

```
.page-h1 {
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1001;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    padding-top: 20px;  
    @media screen and (min-width: 380px) {
      font-size: 16px !important;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    @media screen and(min-width: 420px) {
      font-size: 22px !important;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    @media screen and(min-width: 650px) {
      font-size: 2em;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    @media screen and(min-width: 980px) {
      font-size: 3em;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    @media screen and(min-width: 1400px) {
      font-size: 3.5em;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is only a typo. Have you tried to put an empty space between `and` & `(` in your media queries? You could also remove `!important` rule.

Comment: @ReSedano didn't fix it

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmYWWG I don't see the problem here, sorry.

Comment: Its seen the !important rule is "Passing over" the others mediaquery, i created a pen without the `!important` property and its worked fine, take a look at this https://codepen.io/joaoskr/pen/dQPgLK

Answer (score 0):

It was a minor syntax issue. I just need to add the 'only'.

```
.landing-h1 {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
      font-size: 25px;
      line-height: 23px;
      margin-top: 48%;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      word-spacing: 3px;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 40px) {
      font-size: 30px;
      line-height: 40px;
      margin-top: 33%;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      word-spacing: 5px;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
      font-size: 3.3em;
      line-height: 60px;
      margin-top: 24%;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      word-spacing: 10px;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
      font-size: 5em;
      line-height: 95px;
      margin-top: 16%;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      word-spacing: 15px;
    }
    color: #fccd31;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100001;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 14%;
    font-family: 'Avenir';
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```